# Laurent series at infinity for $f(x) = x\arctan(x)$

Tags: analysis, laurent-series

How would I go about expanding this expression 
$$ f(x) = x\arctan(x)$$
into Laurents series at $x=\infty$. Substituting $y=\frac{1}{x}$ does not help me here, or I just do not understand how it would help.

Comment: Welcome! Is it at $+\infty$ or at $-\infty$?

Comment: It is at $+\infty$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: 
$\arctan x=\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan{\frac1x}$ for all $x>0$